# How to use google font in thymeleaf pdf template

Tags: spring-boot, pdf, thymeleaf, multilingual, google-fonts

I am using this to integrate google font **Roboto** in my thymeleaf pdf template.
But no effect is coming in pdf

`<link th:href="@{http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />`

`<body style="width: 900px; margin: 0 auto; color: #111; line-height: normal; font-family: Roboto; font-size: 12px; box-sizing: border-box;font-style: italic;">`